# jquery ui button() is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In the head section of my mvc application I have references to JQuery and JQuery UI like this:

```
<script src="/MyPortal/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js">
<script src="/MyPortal/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js">
<script src="/MyPortal/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js">
etc.
```

Then I tried simple jQuery UI widgets such as button and buttonset as follows:

```
$("#viewSwitch").buttonset();
```

or

```
$("#myButton").button();
```

Firebug always reports:

```
TypeError: $(...).buttonset is not a function
```

I've double and triple checked in Firebug the script files are loading correctly. 
jQuery there's no problems.

In Firebug's command window, after the page has finished loading with no errors, I type in:

```
jQuery.ui
```

and it comes back as undefined.

Not sure what's left to check or troubleshoot?

Comment: Have you checked that your version of UI is compatible with your version of jQuery? **EDIT: Just checked, it is**

Comment: thanks didn't think of that, but as you said, it is compatible.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is script load order. Could Modernizr be affecting it? Try placing it after jQuery UI and see what happens?

Comment: normally I'd put modernizr first as it doesn't impact jquery at all. In fact I use it across all my applications and websites and it's never impacted jquery or jquery ui before. I'll try and move it to see what happens

Comment: Last question, this is a stupid one but who knows! Is there any code in the jQuery UI .js file? And if so, is it the correct code?

Comment: yip all the code is there and it's correct. And the modernizr shift had no effect

Comment: Oh one final thing... I've had an issue with dodgy caching of old versions of JS files. Try doing either shift+f5 or CTRL+f5 and see if that works in your browser.

Comment: I cleared out my cache too and it didn't work (Shift + Ctrl + Del)

Answer (score 5):

Faced a similar problem today. In my case, the jQuery ui filename didn't match.
The file was named as

```
jqueryui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js
```

And the file was referred to as

```
jqueryui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js
```

jQuery fails silently and I had to waste 3hrs finding the mistake.

**Edit**

Upon further investigation. Now I found another mistake. I previously used 'custom download' option to download the bundle. In that build different widgets were not automatically included in the jqueryui.custom.js file. So none of the widgets were available for use.